# How to add a header into `AuthenticationKeyGenerator`?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

**Context:**
Multiple devices can use the same client credentials and as a result they share tokens, which can lead to race conditions when 2 or more devices try to refresh token. Device identification can be found in headers, so custom `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` implementation can use device id to generate a token per device. Device id can be stored as an additional parameter in `OAuth2Request.getExtensions()`.

**Problem:** As I mentioned, device id is not coming from GET/POST parameters, so it is not present in `OAuth2Request.getRequestParameters()`, but can be found in headers. But `OAuth2Request` is created in `DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory`(implementation of `OAuth2RequestFactory`), which does not have access to the original http request to copy information from headers and add it to `OAuth2Request.getExtensions()`

What is the best way to capture the header and store it inside `OAuth2Request.getExtensions()` for `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` to later use it as a part of the key?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar implementation of AuthenticationKeyGenerator where **device/user agent** was used to generate a key for **auth_to_access** using Redis as a token store.

Below is a code snippet of how I captured the user agent in my custom AuthenticationKeyGenerator implementation

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```